# PSGML conflicts with built-in `sgml-mode`

Tags: indentation, faces, major-mode, html

I’ve installed [psgml 1.4.0-9](https://debian-repo.stanford.edu/debian/pool/main/p/psgml/) and [psgml-html-mode](https://github.com/madsen/psgml-html-mode) for DTD-aware editing of HTML.* But the built-in `sgml-mode`/`html-mode` seems to be causing some problems: some tags are highlighted in `font-lock-function-name-face` (as the built-in `sgml-mode` does), some in `font-lock-type-face` (as PSGML does), and they get recoloured depending on what I do (scrolling generally causes `font-lock-type-face` to take over, but the initial screen full of code is in `font-lock-function-name-face`). Most annoyingly, aiui PSGML is supposed to offer SGML-correct indenting taking account of omitted close tags, but afaict `sgml-mode` is taking control of indentation, meaning when I `indent-region` etc, what happens is not DTD-aware. I also have two SGML entries in my menu bar: the first (the one on the left) is from PSGML, the second from `sgml-mode`.

Given that `sgml-mode.elc` and `sgml-mode.el.gz` are inside my system Emacs installation (which I am reluctant to go hacking around inside by deleting or changing files), how can I completely disable all their behaviour and everything that they’re loading?

* Yes, I’m aware that HTML is not technically an SGML application any more, but the syntax is close enough, and no other HTML editing mode I’m aware of (including `html-mode`, `html-helper-mode`, and the HTML server for `lsp-mode`) is properly aware of implicit close tags in HTML — they think `<p>hello <p>world` creates two nested `p` elements, rather than two consecutive ones. PSGML gets it right.

**Edit:** My setup for PSGML etc, if it helps, is [here.](https://gitlab.com/dpk/dotfiles/-/blob/master/.emacs.d/init.el#L206-215) Everything else needed should also be in the same repo.

Comment: Your links claim that `psgml` provides a major mode, so unless that mode *derives* from `sgml-mode`, the latter won't be having any unintended effects.  If it *does* derive, then the effects are intentional.

Comment: Oh, crazy... psgml.el defines a `sgml-mode` -- indeed *everything* is in the `sgml-` name space, not a `psgml-` name space.  So I think you're just being misled by that.

Comment: No, `describe-function sgml-indent-line` explicitly tells me that it’s picking up the version in `sgml-mode.el` in my Emacs system installation, and not the version defined in `psgml-edit.el`.

Comment: As you are using `(require 'psgml)` the standard `sgml-mode` won't be getting a look in at all, unless something calls `html-mode` (which would autoload `sgml-mode.el`, clobbering `sgml-mode` in the process), or `sgml-mode` is otherwise directly loaded.

Comment: I can't advise the *best* thing to do, because I have no idea whether `psgml`'s `sgml-mode` is compatible with the standard mode.  It's very unusual to see a library stepping on top of another's name like this.  Perhaps they were under development at the same time, though.

Comment: You *could* consider putting your own `sgml-mode.el` earlier in the load path, though, so that anything which attempts to load that library for any reason will load your file instead.  This may or may not cause things to break.

Comment: Aha, doing that causes an error when `init.el` loads, and the debugger reveals that `nxml-mode` is loading `sgml-mode`. Moving the PSGML loading file up above the part of `init.el` which loads `nxml-mode` fixes the problem, although goodness knows what I’m in for next time I actually want `nxml-mode` …

Comment: I don't think it would be mad to create a `psgml2.el` which uses a `psgml` name space and just use that instead, as the currently naming is clearly a problem.  If `psgml` is still maintained, maybe check to see whether there is an existing issue about this, and if not consider raised one, or otherwise discussing it with them.

Comment: As far as I know, the Debian package maintainers are the only people keeping PSGML alive and working on modern Emacs, alas. Perhaps if/when they finally give up on it, I’ll look at doing that.

Comment: It's part of GNU ELPA and evidentially gets some occasional compatibility fixes in there; but most of the development does appear to be old.  http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/psgml.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nxml-mode`, which implicitly loads the built-in `sgml-mode` for a small number of things, is loaded before PSGML. This means a number of names get clobbered before PSGML loads and it can’t properly claim them.

Loading PSGML before `nxml-mode` fixes the problem since Emacs will think `sgml-mode` is already there when `nxml-mode` loads, but `nxml-mode` will no longer work since the definitions it needs from the built-in `sgml-mode` are no longer there.

Solution: [Load `sgml-mode-fix`](https://gitlab.com/dpk/dotfiles/-/blob/master/.emacs.d/lisp/sgml-mode-fix.el), which defines the features and variables from `sgml-mode` which `nxml-mode` depends on, but no others. Since none of these names clash with PSGML, there should be no problem with using PSGML for HTML/other non-XML SGML files and nXML for XML files.

```
(require 'sgml-mode-fix)
(require 'nxml-mode)
;; configure nxml-mode here …
```